# Save file to memory and later write back

Tags: php

I wish to read a file using PHP, and later write it to a directory which doesn't exist at the time of reading the file.  I can't create the directory first as described below.  I do not wish to save it in a temporary directory to prevent possible overwrites.  Am I able to read the file, save it in memory, and later write the file?

WHY I WISH TO DO THIS: I have the following method which empties a directory.  I now have a need to do so but keep one file in the root of the emptied directory.  I recognize I could modify this method to do so, but I rarely need to do so, and may wish another approach.  Instead, before calling this method, I would like to copy the file in question, empty the directory, and then put it back.

```
/**
* Empty directory.  Include subdirectories if $deep is true
*/
public static function emptyDir($dirname,$deep=false)
{
    $dirname=(substr($dirname, -1)=='/')?$dirname:$dirname.'/';
    if(!is_dir($dirname)){return false;}
    // Loop through the folder
    $dir = dir($dirname);
    while (false !== $entry = $dir->read())
    {
        // Skip pointers
        if ($entry == '.' || $entry == '..') {
            continue;
        }
        elseif(is_file($dirname.$entry)) {
            unlink($dirname.$entry);
        }
        elseif($deep && is_dir($dirname.$entry)){
            self::deltree($dirname.$entry);
        }
    }
    // Clean up
    $dir->close();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided this is all done withing the same request, then yes you can.
Just save the file contents to a variable, then write it back again:

```
$temp = file_get_contents('path/to/file.ext');

className::emptyDir($dir);

file_put_contents('path/to/file.ext', $temp);
```

Comment: Thanks Steve.  I've never used `file_get_contents`, and will check it out.  Turns out the file in question is a text string, so this should work.

Comment: @user1032531 Im fairly sure `file_get_contents` is binary safe anyway, so shouldnt be limited to text files

Comment: Steve,  Missed that the first time I looked at the manual.  You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it could be done. Just add a property to your class. So in your class property, there will be the content of the file, while the object is exists, and it did set. It could be a class variable (static) also, so you do not need to instantiate if you do not want.

```
class anything {

    var $fileContent = '';

    public static function emptyDir($dirname,$deep=false) {
        //....
    }

    public function setFileContent($fileOrUrlToRead) {
        $this->fileContent = file_get_contents($fileOrUrlToRead);
    }

    public function saveFile($fileName) {
        file_put_contents($fileName, $this->fileContent);
    }
}

$anything = new anything();
$anything->setFileContent('url_or_path_of_file_to_get');
anything::emptyDir('./media/files/');
$anything->saveFile('./media/files/something.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the session to save the needed information.